# What will be the remainder when $24^{1202}$ is divided by $1446$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, modular-arithmetic

What is the remainder when $24^{1202}$ is divided by $1446$?

---

**My Try :**

$\gcd(24,1446) = 6$

So, By using Euler's theorem, I can write $24^{240} = 1 \pmod {241}$

Hence, $24^{1202} = 24^2 \pmod {241}$

---

How to solve this further to get $1446$ ?

Comment: A dup cannot be more exact than this, so I think I'm not out of line instaclosing this. +1 for showing non-trivial work.